# Sketch $f(x) =\frac{ 2x}{x^2-5x+4}$

Tags: calculus

I have already found the domain, intercepts and critical number along with max and min points. Now when finding the intervals of concavity I understand you must take the second derivative but I can't seem to factor it. If one could justify if i derived it correctly that would be greatly appreciated.

First Derivative: = $\frac{-2x^2+8}{(x^2-5x+4)^2}$

Second Derivative: = $\frac{4(x^3-12x+20)}{(x^2-5x+4)^3}$

Comment: It will probably also help your sketching, if you observe that $x^2-5x+4=(x-1)(x-4)$. You should expect something dramatic to happen to $f(x)$ when $x$ approaches either $1$ or $4$.

Comment: For the first derivative, I believe the $-2x^2$ should be in the numerator of the fraction.

Comment: I notice that before people came and tried to help by editing your post that you were writing things without parenthesis.  You will confuse yourself and others if you are not perfectly clear what it is you are trying to write.  `a+b/c+d` is interpreted as $a+\frac{b}{c}+d$, **not** as $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ or as $a+\frac{b}{c+d}$.  If you do not type with mathjax, then at the very least write it instead as `(a+b)/(c+d)` so there is no confusion.

Comment: Your first derivative is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The first derivative was correct on paper, I'm sure.  The formatting was incorrect and confused people who went to edit.

Comment: @JMoravitz: sorry, I burnt the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Just using common sense and the knowledge that the denominator, which is zero at $x=1$ and $x=4$, is negative between those points and positive outside that range, we can describe the sketch quite well:

- Between $1$ and $4$ $f(x)$ is always negative.  As $x$ approaches $1$ from above or $4$ from below, the curve asymptotically appoaches the lines $x=1$ and $x=4$, respectively.  Somewhere between those two lines, $f(x)$ turns over so that it can go back to negative infinity by the time it reaches $x=4$, so the curve in that region looks like an upside-down infinitely tall cup, with a maximum at roughly $x=2.5$, at which point $y$ is about $-2$.
- Slightly to the left of $x=1$, as we move further to the left,  the curve (which starts at positive infinity at $x=1$) falls rapidly, and by $x=0$ it has just fallen to the origin, which it crosses.
- Since the curve and its derivatives are not discontinuous at $x=0$, it continues to go negative for negative $x$, and in fact $f(x) < 0$ whenever $x<0$.
- But when $x$ his a large negative number, the denominator grows faster than the numerator, so the curve approaches zero from below as $x \to -\infty$.
- Combined with the behavior near the origin, we can deduce that there is some minimum at some negative value of $x$, at which point $f(x)<0$.
- To the right of $x=4$, $f(x)$ starts out at positive infinity, and falls, but it never becomes negative.  $f(x)$ behaves like $2/x$ for very large $x$, approaching the $x$ axis from above.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where did you get the x=1 and x=4 from?

Comment: @Jessica factorise the denominator, what happens when the denominator becomes $0$, do you know how to divide by 0?

Comment: @ZainPatel I totally understand that but, what i am trying to ask is when finding the points of inflection and concavity i am currently getting the above second derivative and when we set that = to 0 we have to factorize the numerator to find the possible P.O.I. But since we can't factorize the numerator what should I do.